# escape uwsgi magic variables

Tags: escaping, uwsgi

I'm using uwsgi to implement a crontab. I'd like to call the unix date command from the crontab. Something like this:

cron2 = minute=50 some_job.py `date "+%Y-%m-%d"` `date -v -1d "+%Y-%m-%d"`

But uwsgi interprets the % modifiers as magic variables. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: figured it out myself already: just need to double the %. I.e., date "+%%Y-%%m-%%d"